# Render template relation ManyToMany Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, controller, doctrine

Please help with this, I am having this problem when I render the template twig in the controller, having problems with relations ManyToMany

Neither the property "nombre" nor one of the methods "nombre()", "getnombre()"/"isnombre()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"....I will put my entities and controller, please help me with this:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Menu
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="menu")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Repository\MenuRepository")
 */
class Menu
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Type(type="float")
     * @ORM\Column(name="precio", type="float")
     */
    private $precio;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Assert\Date()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="date")
     */
    private $fecha;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="fechacomprar", type="datetime")
     */
    private $fechacomprar;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Assert\DateTime()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="fechavence", type="datetime")
     */
    private $fechavence;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Alimento", inversedBy="menu")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="alimento_menu",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="menu_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="alimento_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $alimento;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->alimento = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set precio
     *
     * @param float $precio
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function setPrecio($precio)
    {
        $this->precio = $precio;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get precio
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrecio()
    {
        return $this->precio;
    }

    /**
     * Set fecha
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fecha
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function setFecha($fecha)
    {
        $this->fecha = $fecha;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fecha
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getFecha()
    {
        return $this->fecha;
    }

    /**
     * Set fechacomprar
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fechacomprar
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function setFechacomprar($fechacomprar)
    {
        $this->fechacomprar = $fechacomprar;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fechacomprar
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getFechacomprar()
    {
        return $this->fechacomprar;
    }

    /**
     * Set fechavence
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fechavence
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function setFechavence($fechavence)
    {
        $this->fechavence = $fechavence;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fechavence
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getFechavence()
    {
        return $this->fechavence;
    }


    /**
     * Add alimento
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\Alimento $alimento
     *
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function addAlimento(Alimento $alimento)
    {
        $this->alimento[] = $alimento;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove alimento
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\Alimento $alimento
     */
    public function removeAlimento(Alimento $alimento)
    {
        $this->alimento->removeElement($alimento);
    }

    /**
     * Get alimento
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAlimento()
    {
        return $this->alimento;
    }
}


<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert;


/**
 * Alimento
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="alimento")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Repository\AlimentoRepository")
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity("nombre")
 */
class Alimento
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Debe escribir un alimento")
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/\d/", match=false, message="Debe escribir un nombre válido")
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var float
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Debe especificar un precio")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="Debe escribir un precio válido")
     * @ORM\Column(name="precio", type="float")
     */
    private $precio;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TipoAlimento")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $tipo;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Menu", mappedBy="alimento")
     */
    private $menu;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param string $nombre
     *
     * @return Alimento
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Set precio
     *
     * @param float $precio
     *
     * @return Alimento
     */
    public function setPrecio($precio)
    {
        $this->precio = $precio;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get precio
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrecio()
    {
        return $this->precio;
    }

    /**
     * Set tipo
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\TipoAlimento $tipo
     *
     * @return Alimento
     */
    public function setTipo(TipoAlimento $tipo)
    {
        $this->tipo = $tipo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tipo
     *
     * @return \AdminBundle\Entity\TipoAlimento
     */
    public function getTipo()
    {
        return $this->tipo;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getNombre();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->menu = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add menu
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\Menu $menu
     *
     * @return Alimento
     */
    public function addMenu(Menu $menu)
    {
        $this->menu[] = $menu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove menu
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\Menu $menu
     */
    public function removeMenu(Menu $menu)
    {
        $this->menu->removeElement($menu);
    }

    /**
     * Get menu
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getMenu()
    {
        return $this->menu;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $menu = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Menu')->findAll();
        return $this->render('AdminBundle:menu:index.html.twig', array(
            'menu' => $menu,
        ));`enter code here`
    }
```

And in the template I am doing the things like this:

```
 {% for m in menu %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ m.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.fecha | date('d/m/y') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.alimento.nombre }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.fechacomprar | date('d/m/y') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.fechavence | date('d/m/y') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.precio }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Problem here is m.alimento.nombre is wrong!

Comment: m.alimento is a collection. Try {% for alimento in m.alimento %}  {{ alimento.nombre }}  {% endfor %}

Comment: show your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can try this, in this case, m.alimento will return Alimento's  __toString

```
{{  m.alimento|join(',') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a many to many that means that each menu will have many alimentos so you have to loop over each of them.

```
{% for a in m.alimento %}
<td>{{ a.nombre }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Owww, I can't believe this, I have been having this problem two days, and right now is fixed, thanks, really,thanks!.....this web is the best!